# Cocos2dx Android App Crash on Device “Java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity”, “Java.lang.NullPointerException”

Tags: android, mobile, android-activity, cocos2d-x

I am following [Raywenderlich tutorial of cocos2dx for android build](http://www.raywenderlich.com/33750/cocos2d-x-tutorial-for-ios-and-android-getting-started) and I am using ndk-r8d and cocos2d-2.1beta3-x-2.1.0 for this. I just created a sample project and my app crashes on android device with the following log. Help me !!!!

```
04-07 23:33:44.777: E/AndroidRuntime(24626): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-07 23:33:44.777: E/AndroidRuntime(24626): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.softmasters.me/com.softmasters.me.me}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-07 23:33:44.777: E/AndroidRuntime(24626):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2826)
04-07 23:33:44.777: E/AndroidRuntime(24626):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2855)
04-07 23:33:44.777: E/AndroidRuntime(24626):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2300)
04-07 23:33:44.777: E/AndroidRuntime(24626):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
04-07 23:33:44.777: E/AndroidRuntime(24626):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
04-07 23:33:44.777: E/AndroidRuntime(24626):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-07 23:33:44.777: E/AndroidRuntime(24626):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
04-07 23:33:44.777: E/AndroidRuntime(24626):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
04-07 23:33:44.777: E/AndroidRuntime(24626):    at  java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-07 23:33:44.777: E/AndroidRuntime(24626):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-07 23:33:44.777: E/AndroidRuntime(24626):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
04-07 23:33:44.777: E/AndroidRuntime(24626):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
04-07 23:33:44.777: E/AndroidRuntime(24626):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-07 23:33:44.777: E/AndroidRuntime(24626): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-07 23:33:44.777: E/AndroidRuntime(24626):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.onResume(GLSurfaceView.java:569)
04-07 23:33:44.777: E/AndroidRuntime(24626):    at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView.onResume(Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView.java:158)
04-07 23:33:44.777: E/AndroidRuntime(24626):    at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxActivity.onResume(Cocos2dxActivity.java:76)
04-07 23:33:44.777: E/AndroidRuntime(24626):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1202)
04-07 23:33:44.777: E/AndroidRuntime(24626):    at  android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5345)
04-07 23:33:44.777: E/AndroidRuntime(24626):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2816)
04-07 23:33:44.777: E/AndroidRuntime(24626):    ... 12 more
```

Comment: I didn't use cocos2d yet, but your stacktrace indicates that the problem is caused in the onResume method.

Comment: @donfuxx I am not expert in android. can you suggest some peace of code for onRusume method.

Comment: Android Activities have lifecycle methods. One of them is onResume. Reading through the stacktrace cocos2d seems to implement that at Cocos2dxActivity.onResume

Comment: @donfuxx I put following code but same results...
public void onResume(){

  super.onResume();
     // put your code here...

 }

Answer (score 0):

Try to run "./build_native.sh clean" and after that "./build_native.sh" The app can't run because no found the cocos2d-x compiled files.

Be sure the build native run correctly without any error.